# Ошибка при компиляции std::thread

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, c++11

Доброго времени суток.

Начал учить потоки за 11 стандартом в Qt!

Вот у меня есть простенький код:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void func();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyThread th1;
    th1.run();

   return a.exec();
}
void func()
{ 
    cout << "This string from thread!"<<endl;
}
```

Так вот, на вторую строчку (библиотеку thread) ругается компилятор, мол, не знает такой.
Я читал, что нужно в файле с расширением `.pro` дописать `CONFIG   += c++11`. Дописал, но ничего не изменилось!

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

**Обновление**

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <QThread>

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "This string from thread!"<<endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    std::thread t(foo);
    std::t.join();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Почему компилятор ругается?

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более информативные заголовки вопросов, чтобы из них хоть как-то можно было понять контекст.

Comment: Какой компилятор? Какая ОС? qmake повторно вызвали после редактировния .pro-файла?

Answer (score 1):

А где у Вас объявлен класс MyThread? В Qt такого вроде нет, в стандартной библиотеке такого тоже нет, он там называется [std::thread](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread).

**upd**

Если хочется использовать треды от c++11, то вот рабочий код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "This string from thread!"<<std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::thread t(foo);
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

компилировать так

```
g++ thr.cpp -std=c++11 -pthread
```

И это работает перпендикулярно к Qt.

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Comment: Потому что теперь Вы подключили библиотку потоков Qt, а в коде пытаетесь использовать из стандартной библиотеки.

Answer (score 0):

А почему не реализовать поток как указано в документации Qt. Там есть отличный класс QThread. Единственное что с ним нужно поучиться правильно работать. Вот отличная статья на тему многопоточности в Qt http://habrahabr.ru/post/202312/